# Dropdown populated using javascript showing only 'Undefined' in the dropdown options

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using A javascript MEthod to populate Dropdown list as following but getting many 'Undefined' in my dropdown options-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopup()
    {
        $("#wrapper").html('');
        $.get('getClanLeads', function(data){

         var options = '';
         $.each(data, function(i,data){
            options +='<option value="'+ data.user_id +'">' + data.user_id + '</option>';
        });
         $("#wrapper").append('<select>' + options + '</select>');
         alert(data);
         location.href = "#divModalDialog1";
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: When you alert(data), is the right data displayed ?

Comment: @Karim AG data is correctly alert. The Data is-
[{"user_id":3},{"user_id":4}]

Comment: can you post 'getClanLeads' code ?

Comment: public function getClanLeads()
    {
        $clanLeads = Userclanmapping::where('active', '=', '1')->where('clan_id', '=', function($query) {
                    $query->select('clanid')
                            ->from(with(new Clan)->getTable())
                            ->where('clan_admin', '=', Session::get('userid'));
                })->get(array('user_id'));
        return $clanLeads;
    }

Answer (score 0):

`options +='<option value="'+ data.user_id +'">' + data.user_id + '</option>';`

Try change

```
data.user_id
```

to

```
data.user_id.value
```

Comment: Soryy But this not Working for me